# How to do a training and matching for 3D object recognition from Viewpoint Feature Histogram?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, training-data, object-recognition

I would like to build a 3D object recognition for my project reaserch, I have clustered for each object that I will recognize, and I have also calculated the VFH. My question is, after that what should I do?, how to make training data to make the recognition?, and how do I match the object to the scene?

I am using ROS C++ and Pointcloud library

Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 2):

On [pointclouds.org](http://pointclouds.org) you can find a [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/vfh_recognition.php#vfh-recognition) explaining exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: it is nice of you to helping